# Data is not being passed through Prepare through segue

Tags: swift, variables, segue

I am trying to pass a userID string through a segue, I know how to do this and I will show my code below, but when I try and use the variable that has been set to when the segue it is equal to nill, I would like to know why is this and how do I resolve it

my prepare for segue function

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "go"){
            let userID = self.view.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
            let vc = segue.destination as? selectedListing
            vc?.userID = (userID.text!)
        }

    }
```

my viewDidLoad and set up of userID variable

```
var userID : String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        print("user:"+userID)
 }
```

When I print the value of let userID within the prepareForSegue it prints what I would like but when the view loads in the separate view which has been segued to it printed nill

Comment: Force unwrap `selectedListing` (by the way classes should be named with a starting capital letter). The code must not crash. If if does it indicates a design error.

Comment: thanks great it works!